# asynchronous job in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have been given a task where it should be possible for a user to pass some information to a database table.

The table should be seen as a queue.

My question is:

Is it possible to execute some code on the webserver asynchronously, so the users can use the website for others tasks meanwhile processing the queue?

Is it possible to use the Thread class and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Asynchronous Pages as a start - it is teh easiest way to do what you describe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service bus to get this done.  If you feel up to it you could have a look at my open source esb:

http://shuttle.codeplex.com

It has an implementation that can use a sql table as a queue.